# Wpf windows freeze when other thread starts to do some job

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

is there anything in WPF that do in WindowsForms the method "DoEvents"?

I am asking this because i am trying to use COM Interop in a thread, and when it is doing his job the ProgressBar is being updated.

I can't find anything that seems to be easy to do this.

I don't have too much time to be reading and implementing some crazy things, i am almost quitting and leaving the ProgressBar with the Property IsIndeterminate as True.

Comment: You do realize that you weren't supposed to use `DoEvents` for this in WinForms either, right? Do the other job on a separate thread. Long-running tasks like this one don't ever belong on the UI thread, whether it's WPF or WinForms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following example shows you, how to execute some action in another thread than the UI-thread. I don't know a lot about COM, therefore I can not say how this combines with COM-calls, but for the .net-side, this should help you without reading a lot. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) you find the documentation.

```
BackgroundWorker bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker() { WorkerReportsProgress=true};  
bgWorker.DoWork += (s, e) => {      

    // As your requested, here an example on how you yould instantiate your working class,
    //  registering to some progresse event and relay the progress to the backgorund-worker:

    YourClass workingInstance=new YourClass();
    workingInstance.WorkProgress+=(o,yourProgressEvent)=>{
       bgWorker.ReportProgress(yourProgressEvent.ProgressPercentage);
    };
    workingInstance.Execute();

};  
bgWorker.ProgressChanged+=(s,e)=>{      
    // Here you will be informed about progress and here it is save to change/show progress. 
    // You can access from here savely a ProgressBars or another control.  
};  
bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) => {      
// Here you will be informed if the job is done. 
// Use this event to unlock your gui 
};  
bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Although I do not recommend to use it, here a code-example that does something like you know from DoEvents:

```
DispatcherFrame frame = new DispatcherFrame();
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new DispatcherOperationCallback(delegate(object parameter) {
                frame.Continue = false;
                return null;
            }), null);
            Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
```

Comment: Ok but if i have what i am doing in COM Interop in a Class. How can i report the progress to the ProgressChanged event?

Comment: @Miguel: Don't know your scenario, but maybe you could add an event to this class that reports about the progress? Then the callee can register to this event.

Comment: Can you give something like an example to what you are suggesting?

Comment: @Miguel: I have changed my example a little. Hope this leads you to the solution...